# Simple Animation XDK

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

[image]

Why is this keep happening to me? 
Cant do a simple animation on a button... i've been trying to search all over google but can't find it

Comment: Can u add the code that is doing animation

Answer (score 0):

look like u have `-webkit- transition` instead of `-webkit-transition`

there is no space between `-webkit-` and `transition`